Debian 12 crashes randomly as a KVM host
A have installed Debian 12 in an machine who services as a kvm host to 2 guests which are an Ubuntu 22.04 and an Windows 10.
Sometimes the Debian crashes. Initially the video is lost and the cpu cooler goes to maximum speed.
In the first minutes it is possible to ssh connect the debian from aother machine but at last it crashes totally.
Some events seems to trigger the crash.

Once when I put the Ubuntu in full screen
When I opened the TeamViewer in the Windows 10
Other situations I do not remember

Sometimes I can use the kvm guest for some hours without problem and other times it crash after some minutes of use.
I tried to see the log in /var/log/libvirt/qemu/ but I did not see any useful
# tail  /var/log/libvirt/qemu/win10.log 
Repairing cluster 9535489 refcount=1 reference=0
Repairing cluster 9568257 refcount=1 reference=0
Repairing cluster 9601025 refcount=1 reference=0
Repairing cluster 9633793 refcount=1 reference=0

Maybe is it not possible to use Windows 10 as a guest of kvm in Debian?
Both guest VM are in almost default configuration.
The video is Virtio. I have tried QXL either but the behaviour seems to be the same.
Below is the xml of the video configuration
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>

Now the Debian have a new crash and no virtual machine were running, which shows the cause is not the VM. Below is the logs that comes from journalctl
Sep 21 19:32:58 debian-rz7 geoclue[3258]: Failed to query location: Failed to query location: Not Found
Sep 21 19:33:06 debian-rz7 rtkit-daemon[1058]: Supervising 11 threads of 8 processes of 1 users.
Sep 21 19:33:06 debian-rz7 rtkit-daemon[1058]: Supervising 11 threads of 8 processes of 1 users.
Sep 21 19:33:30 debian-rz7 geoclue[3258]: Failed to query location: Failed to query location: Not Found
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 10125 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/disp/gv100.c:274 gv100_head_state+0xe6/0x100 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bridge stp llc qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc uinput intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd btusb btrtl btbcm iwlmvm btintel kvm btmtk snd_hda_codec_realtek irqbypass snd_hda_codec_generic bluetooth snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 snd_hda_intel snd_usb_audio videobuf2_vmalloc snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 jitterentropy_rng videobuf2_memops snd_intel_sdw_acpi videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_codec videobuf2_common sha512_ssse3 snd_usbmidi_lib sha512_generic snd_rawmidi iwlwifi videodev ctr snd_hda_core snd_seq_device eeepc_wmi aesni_intel asus_wmi snd_hwdep mc drbg asus_ec_sensors crypto_simd battery snd_pcm ch341 cryptd ansi_cprng platform_profile ftdi_sio
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  cfg80211 sparse_keymap ecdh_generic snd_timer joydev rapl ledtrig_audio ecc usbserial wmi_bmof snd sp5100_tco ccp pcspkr soundcore watchdog k10temp rfkill sg evdev acpi_cpufreq msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport dm_mod fuse efi_pstore loop configfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau video drm_display_helper cec rc_core drm_ttm_helper sd_mod ttm ahci drm_kms_helper libahci xhci_pci libata xhci_hcd nvme r8169 drm crc32_pclmul nvme_core usbcore realtek crc32c_intel mdio_devres t10_pi scsi_mod igb mxm_wmi libphy crc64_rocksoft i2c_piix4 crc64 crc_t10dif dca scsi_common crct10dif_generic usb_common i2c_algo_bit crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common wmi button
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CPU: 14 PID: 10125 Comm: kworker/u64:0 Not tainted 6.1.0-25-amd64 #1  Debian 6.1.106-3
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG STRIX X570-E GAMING, BIOS 2408 07/24/2020
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RIP: 0010:gv100_head_state+0xe6/0x100 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Code: 78 e8 ee ca 51 e8 ba 18 00 00 00 c1 e8 04 83 e0 0f 83 f8 04 74 16 ba 1e 00 00 00 83 f8 05 74 0c ba 12 00 00 00 83 f8 01 74 02 <0f> 0b 88 55 14 5b 5d 41 5c e9 cc 5c de e8 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffae1519257ab0 EFLAGS: 00010002
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RAX: 000000000000000f RBX: 0000000000008000 RCX: 0000000000000028
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000012 RSI: ffff967182f55bc8 RDI: ffffae151368a004
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RBP: ffff967182f55bc8 R08: ffff9671a44104a8 R09: ffffae1519257cb8
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: R10: 0000000000000030 R11: 000000000000000c R12: ffff967162db2c00
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: R13: 0000000000000028 R14: ffffae1519257b58 R15: 0000000000000040
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff96802ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CR2: 00007fcb543bbf00 CR3: 000000010e09c000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Call Trace:
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  <TASK>
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? __warn+0x7d/0xc0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? gv100_head_state+0xe6/0x100 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? report_bug+0xe2/0x150
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? handle_bug+0x41/0x70
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? exc_invalid_op+0x13/0x60
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x16/0x20
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? gv100_head_state+0xe6/0x100 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  nvkm_head_mthd_scanoutpos+0x74/0xf0 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0xd8/0x180 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  nvif_object_mthd+0xcb/0x200 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  nouveau_display_scanoutpos+0x91/0x150 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? nouveau_display_vblank_disable+0x20/0x20 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  drm_crtc_vblank_helper_get_vblank_timestamp_internal+0x14e/0x360 [drm]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  drm_get_last_vbltimestamp+0xad/0xc0 [drm]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  drm_update_vblank_count+0x8f/0x3c0 [drm]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  drm_vblank_enable+0x14c/0x180 [drm]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  drm_vblank_get+0x96/0xe0 [drm]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  nv50_disp_atomic_commit_tail+0x35a/0x7e0 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x90/0x2d0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  process_one_work+0x1c7/0x380
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x380
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  kthread+0xda/0x100
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  </TASK>
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 10125 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvif/timer.c:36 nvif_timer_wait_test+0x62/0x70 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bridge stp llc qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc uinput intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd btusb btrtl btbcm iwlmvm btintel kvm btmtk snd_hda_codec_realtek irqbypass snd_hda_codec_generic bluetooth snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 snd_hda_intel snd_usb_audio videobuf2_vmalloc snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 jitterentropy_rng videobuf2_memops snd_intel_sdw_acpi videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_codec videobuf2_common sha512_ssse3 snd_usbmidi_lib sha512_generic snd_rawmidi iwlwifi videodev ctr snd_hda_core snd_seq_device eeepc_wmi aesni_intel asus_wmi snd_hwdep mc drbg asus_ec_sensors crypto_simd battery snd_pcm ch341 cryptd ansi_cprng platform_profile ftdi_sio
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  cfg80211 sparse_keymap ecdh_generic snd_timer joydev rapl ledtrig_audio ecc usbserial wmi_bmof snd sp5100_tco ccp pcspkr soundcore watchdog k10temp rfkill sg evdev acpi_cpufreq msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport dm_mod fuse efi_pstore loop configfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau video drm_display_helper cec rc_core drm_ttm_helper sd_mod ttm ahci drm_kms_helper libahci xhci_pci libata xhci_hcd nvme r8169 drm crc32_pclmul nvme_core usbcore realtek crc32c_intel mdio_devres t10_pi scsi_mod igb mxm_wmi libphy crc64_rocksoft i2c_piix4 crc64 crc_t10dif dca scsi_common crct10dif_generic usb_common i2c_algo_bit crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common wmi button
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CPU: 14 PID: 10125 Comm: kworker/u64:0 Tainted: G        W          6.1.0-25-amd64 #1  Debian 6.1.106-3
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG STRIX X570-E GAMING, BIOS 2408 07/24/2020
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RIP: 0010:nvif_timer_wait_test+0x62/0x70 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Code: 18 c7 43 20 01 00 00 00 48 2b 43 10 48 39 43 08 73 df 48 c7 c0 92 ff ff ff 5b e9 e9 55 e6 e8 8d 4a 01 89 4b 20 83 fa 10 75 de <0f> 0b eb e4 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 3a
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffae1519257da0 EFLAGS: 00010246
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffff RBX: ffffae1519257db0 RCX: 0000000000000011
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000010 RSI: 000000000000000e RDI: ffffae1501090084
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RBP: 000000000000001c R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: R10: 000000000000000e R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff967140ef9000
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: R13: ffff967193b0fc00 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff96714e7ca600
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff96802ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CR2: 00007fcb543bbf00 CR3: 000000010e09c000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Call Trace:
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  <TASK>
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? __warn+0x7d/0xc0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? nvif_timer_wait_test+0x62/0x70 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? report_bug+0xe2/0x150
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? handle_bug+0x41/0x70
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? exc_invalid_op+0x13/0x60
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x16/0x20
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? nvif_timer_wait_test+0x62/0x70 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  base507c_ntfy_wait_begun+0x81/0xd0 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  nv50_disp_atomic_commit_tail+0x5ae/0x7e0 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x90/0x2d0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  process_one_work+0x1c7/0x380
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x380
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  kthread+0xda/0x100
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  </TASK>
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: nouveau 0000:0b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 10125 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/disp/gv100.c:274 gv100_head_state+0xe6/0x100 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bridge stp llc qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc uinput intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd btusb btrtl btbcm iwlmvm btintel kvm btmtk snd_hda_codec_realtek irqbypass snd_hda_codec_generic bluetooth snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel uvcvideo sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 snd_hda_intel snd_usb_audio videobuf2_vmalloc snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 jitterentropy_rng videobuf2_memops snd_intel_sdw_acpi videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_codec videobuf2_common sha512_ssse3 snd_usbmidi_lib sha512_generic snd_rawmidi iwlwifi videodev ctr snd_hda_core snd_seq_device eeepc_wmi aesni_intel asus_wmi snd_hwdep mc drbg asus_ec_sensors crypto_simd battery snd_pcm ch341 cryptd ansi_cprng platform_profile ftdi_sio
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel:  cfg80211 sparse_keymap ecdh_generic snd_timer joydev rapl ledtrig_audio ecc usbserial wmi_bmof snd sp5100_tco ccp pcspkr soundcore watchdog k10temp rfkill sg evdev acpi_cpufreq msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport dm_mod fuse efi_pstore loop configfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau video drm_display_helper cec rc_core drm_ttm_helper sd_mod ttm ahci drm_kms_helper libahci xhci_pci libata xhci_hcd nvme r8169 drm crc32_pclmul nvme_core usbcore realtek crc32c_intel mdio_devres t10_pi scsi_mod igb mxm_wmi libphy crc64_rocksoft i2c_piix4 crc64 crc_t10dif dca scsi_common crct10dif_generic usb_common i2c_algo_bit crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common wmi button
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: CPU: 14 PID: 10125 Comm: kworker/u64:0 Tainted: G        W          6.1.0-25-amd64 #1  Debian 6.1.106-3
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG STRIX X570-E GAMING, BIOS 2408 07/24/2020
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: RIP: 0010:gv100_head_state+0xe6/0x100 [nouveau]
Sep 21 19:33:37 debian-rz7 kernel: Code: 78 e8 ee ca 51 e8 ba 18 00 00 00 c1 e8 04 83 e0 0f 83 f8 04 74 16 ba 1e 00 00 00 83 f8 05 74 0c ba 12 00 00 00 83 f8 01 74 02 <0f> 0b 88 55 14 5b 5d 41 5c e9 cc 5c de e8 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00


I was not able to interpret properly this logs. Mayb the problem is in the video card?

Sounds to me more like an hardware issue. You might update your BIOS/UEFI. Please share a possible last seconds log of you host and guest systems.

@paladin in some hours I can take the log. Now the computer is in the Windows boot. Later I will reboot to Debian and do that. Do you have examples of a log to take? Do you mean something like dmesg? By the way, I use the Windows at my work and if I get a stable vm via visrsh in Debian I will chage to that way. Some weeks ago I lost my windows and had to reinstall. I have the hope that using Windows at virsh VM it could be a good way to keep a backup. My last backup from the Widnows was via dd and I was not able to restore it back to my sdd.

This looks more than a driver problem, as nouveau is known to be somewhat unstable. You may try to install the official closed-source driver, but no guarantees. In any case, your platform STRIX X570-E GAMING must have a provision to use some "built-in" graphics of AMD processor, try removing Nvidia card for a moment to try and see if that helps.

@NikitaKipriyanov I think my processor (AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor)  does not have graphical support. So I need the graphic card. However after I have installed the proprietary nvidia driver I am  using the Debian with 2 virtual machines open (windows 10, Ubuntu 22) for something around 3 hours with no problems until now. Why did you say "more than driver problem"? Is not nouveau the open source driver I was using before?

Admittedly I've just been distracted and did not read what I wrote, that must have been "more like a driver problem", of course. Glad to see the driver change helped. Yes, nouveau is a reverse-engineered open source driver for Nvidia cards, developed with no input from their side and it is known to be buggy; even Linus's middle finger to Nvidia didn't promt them to reconsider their approach to Linux support for their hardware, which is why I personally chose to boycott them.

Also, if you have a server machine and system is already installed, you don't need a video card anymore and it can be removed, unless you're going to sit and work at the machine.

@NikitaKipriyanov, if I knew before about Nvidia problem I could try buy other brand. There is no so much option however. The alternative would be AMD-ATI? Now there is no much sense in not using the card since I have already bought it. About using the machine, yes at least now I use directly this machine. My idea is to have a easy way to boot all system I need to my work, having a easy and safety way to make a backup of all of them. Thanks anyway

The Debian VM host is the one with the symptoms of rebooting mysteriously. Investigate what could have caused it to crash.
Check for hardware errors, ECC memory and similar.  On Linux use rasdaemon.
Configure remote syslog logging to a different host, on both VM hosts and VM gusts. Messages sent over IP have a chance of being sent even if they might fail to be committed to local storage. Naturally this would need to be different hardware than the Debian server.
Configure Linux kernel to crash dump (Ubuntu documentation, Debian should be similar).  Like a crashed program dump, but the operating system.  Consider enabling remote kdump, to transfer it out via ssh.  With a copy of the exact kernel version used and this dump, you can do debugger things.  Most basic being  bt to get a backtrace.
So far this is just categories of things to look at. You still need to identify possible root causes and track them down.
When the Debian hosts crashes again, find that exact time in logs. Work backwards from each boot and examine the very last messages logged before the problem. Probably a kernel panic would log quite different messages compared to a planned shutdown.  Examine the dump file, to check it did crash, and what was on CPU in a debugger.
Several categories of problems are possible:

Hardware fault, fixed by replacing problem component.
Operating system fault, so Linux crashed. Find which subsystem is involved, from panic message and dump.
Application crash. Probably on the VM host given the server is rebooting symptoms you describe. However also check logs in guest around the problem time, to see what if anything was happening then.


Thanks John Mahowald. I will try to get all these logs as soon as possible. I put my hardware configuration in my profile in case it can be useful

Which would be the best way to add the logs? Do I put a new answer or edit my question? I found the command: "journalctl -o short-precise -k -b -1" that shows the logs from the last boot, but I did not find something I could associated to a error, By the way, the Debian crashed just now. It did not reboot but it hangs with no video

Another question. If Debian is unstable to use Kvm. Is there some Linux distribution more stable that I could try. Should I try Ubuntu?

I have identified I do not have ECC memory. Now I will follow the other suggestions

Debian is pretty stable to use as a KVM host. Debian is very stable in principle, that is one of their core goals: to not be a bleeding edge, but free and stable. There is a very good principle though: to not combine virtualization with other workloads, the system must be a VM host or something else, but not both. // There is Proxmox VE which is a KVM virtualization platform based on Debian. You should definitely try it.

Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov. Do you know if using Proxmox  do I have to access  the Guest from another computer using something like RDP (windows) or can I open and use the Guest from inside the host? I do not need to install others features in the host beyond kvm but I need to open the Guest from inside the host. Thanks again.

You can open the remote screen in browser with noVNC, or with remote viewer with SPICE; the latter supports multiple virtual displays, forwarding local USB devices to the remote, transferring the sound, clipboard synchronization and so on, although it requires you to install support tool (vdagent) in the VM. On the other hand, it is recommended to install paravirtual drivers and qemu guest agent in the guest anyway (this is not unique to Proxmox; all virtualization technologies offer such guest tools anyway, and PV drivers and tools Promox uses are common for all KVM-based virtualization).

After the Debian have crashed without any virtual machine running I have edit the question adding the logs. Now I installed the Nvidia driver  and will wait a little to see if the system keep stable
